# c#, get information from the site

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to parse the following HTML file, I'd like the get the value of key. This is being done on Silverlight for Windows phone.

```
</tr>
<tr><td width="26"><div style="width: 26px; height: 1px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="1" /></div></td><td width="60" id="tbtime">10:00</td><td width="70%" id="tbcol"><a href="/repertoir/filminfo.php?id=596">Ральф</a></td><td width="30%" id="tbcol" align="center">100 руб.</td></tr><tr><td width="26" height="4"><div style="width: 26px; height: 4px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="4" /></div></td><td width="60"></td><td width="100%" colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td width="26"><div style="width: 26px; height: 1px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="1" /></div></td><td width="60" id="tbtime">12:00</td><td width="70%" id="tbcol"><a href="/repertoir/filminfo.php?id=595"> Сумерки. Сага. Рассвет: Часть 2</a></td><td width="30%" id="tbcol" align="center">100 - 120 руб.</td></tr><tr><td width="26" height="4"><div style="width: 26px; height: 4px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="4" /></div></td><td width="60"></td><td width="100%" colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td width="26"><div style="width: 26px; height: 1px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="1" /></div></td><td width="60" id="tbtime">14:20</td><td width="70%" id="tbcol"><a href="/repertoir/filminfo.php?id=595"> Сумерки. Сага. Рассвет: Часть 2</a></td><td width="30%" id="tbcol" align="center">120 - 150 руб.</td></tr><tr><td width="26" height="4"><div style="width: 26px; height: 4px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="4" /></div></td><td width="60"></td><td width="100%" colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td width="26"><div style="width: 26px; height: 1px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="1" /></div></td><td width="60" id="tbtime">16:40</td><td width="70%" id="tbcol"><a href="/repertoir/filminfo.php?id=607">Бункер</a></td><td width="30%" id="tbcol" align="center">150 руб.</td></tr><tr><td width="26" height="4"><div style="width: 26px; height: 4px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="4" /></div></td><td width="60"></td><td width="100%" colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td width="26"><div style="width: 26px; height: 1px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="1" /></div></td><td width="60" id="tbtime">18:40</td><td width="70%" id="tbcol"><a href="/repertoir/filminfo.php?id=595"> Сумерки. Сага. Рассвет: Часть 2</a></td><td width="30%" id="tbcol" align="center">150 - 180 руб.</td></tr><tr><td width="26" height="4"><div style="width: 26px; height: 4px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="4" /></div></td><td width="60"></td><td width="100%" colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td width="26"><div style="width: 26px; height: 1px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="1" /></div></td><td width="60" id="tbtime">21:00</td><td width="70%" id="tbcol"><a href="/repertoir/filminfo.php?id=595"> Сумерки. Сага. Рассвет: Часть 2</a></td><td width="30%" id="tbcol" align="center">150 - 180 руб.</td></tr><tr><td width="26" height="4"><div style="width: 26px; height: 4px;"><spacer type="block" width="26" height="4" /></div></td><td width="60"></td><td width="100%" colspan="2"></td></tr></table>
<br /><br />
<br /><br />

 public void myparsing()
    {          
       HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        document.LoadHtml(webClient.DownloadString("http://udokan.chita.ru/"));
        var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body/table/tr/td[4]/table");
        if (node != null)
        {
            var innerText = node.InnerText;              
            richTextBox1.AppendText(innerText);
        }       

    }
```

i want to get info about repertoir, but i can't. I have problems with HttpAgilityPack. Method SelectNodes not work.
Help me please and i'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but from the top of my head I have a thought:

Keep in Mind that WebClient and Silverlight work asynchronusly. So make sure the Html is downloaded before passing it into the LoadHtml method. So it would be better to work with DownloadStringAsync and load the document in the complete Callback.

I would start with a copy of the html source as string and check if the XPath query is correct.

Looking at your html site and the source there is no "//body/table/tr/td[4]/table"

There is 1 table in //body/table which has 4 TD Elements but keep in Mind this is a zero based index Array... so the td[3] would be the forth elemen...

So theses are just some thought and I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
        public void MyParsing()
    {
        const string baseUrl = "http://udokan.chita.ru/";
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(webClient.DownloadString(baseUrl));
        var htmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        if (htmlNodeCollection != null)
        {
            foreach (var link in htmlNodeCollection)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(link.Attributes["href"].Value.Contain("repert"))
                    {
                    var newUrl = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), link.Attributes["href"].Value).AbsoluteUri;
                    var queries = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Join(string.Empty, newUrl.Split('?').Skip(1)));
                    var id = queries["id"];
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(id);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

    }
```